# Is a non-negative quadratic polynomial always a sum of squares?

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite, sums-of-squares

I am studying positive semi-definite matrices. A natural problem arises when we study the properties of the corresponding quadratic form of such matrices: **Can we always represent such quadratic forms as sums of squares (of course, of linear terms)?**

I am aware that a high-degree, non-negative polynomial need not be a sum of squares (the $6$-th degree [Motzkin’s Example](https://jump.dev/SumOfSquares.jl/stable/generated/Getting%20started/motzkin) shows that). But if we are restricting this to only second-degree polynomials, does this still hold true?

I really appreciate any insight/hint for my question.

Comment: Yes, you can always do a linear change of variable to make it a signed sum of squares. If some square has negative sign, you can make all other squares zero and that square negative. See, one algorithm [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1388421/1198684)

Comment: Cholesky-decompose the matrix